# Request for my id to be deleted

Tags: support, deleted-accounts, contests

I have been put off by math.stackexchange's policy on people posting questions from ongoing math contests. A very recent violation occurred here: [Triangle Geometry Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203172/triangle-geometry-question) and I believe moderators will not divulge IP addresses of those who abused the system.

As a contestant on the Online math open I feel angry at inaction. I raised the question here:
[math.SE policy on question from ongoing contests](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6206/math-se-policy-on-question-from-ongoing-contests) and I am not happy with this.

I request the mod to delete my account on this site (you may keep the questions as you please) as a mark of solidarity for all my fellow high school students who compete in the olympiads and work hard for them. I also subscribe to self imposed standards of intellectual honesty and I am afraid by using math.stackexchange.com any further, I am collaborating with a website which does tolerate cheaters.
Thank you. Goodbye math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Just FYI, the moderators are not allowed to make private information like IP addresses public even if they wanted, as they are bound by a moderator agreement. The SE privacy policy forbids them this.

Comment: Too late for None, but once your account is deleted, you have forfeited your ability to advocate change.

Comment: It just occurred to me to wonder whether anyone has ever made a request for an ego or superego to be deleted.

Comment: @GerryMyerson on other parts of the internet I *frequently* find myself *wishing* that some egos could be deleted. Or at least deflated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please delete this account.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10342/please-delete-this-account)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: other way round; [that question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10342) would be a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 62):

In the comments to Qiaochu's comment, there is a dispute about whether moderators should delete/close questions from ongoing contests rapidly before they can attract answers. For example, Bill Dubuque writes "moderators should not execute unilatateral deletions on such contentious matters..." while Jonas Meyer writes "we would want a moderator to be able to [delete/lock these questions] in a timely fashion...".

I would like to poll the community, in the standard manner.

**VOTE THIS ANSWER UP TO SUPPORT the moderators rapidly deleting or closing questions from ongoing contests**, without waiting to seek consensus from the broader community.

I strongly support such closures, and will probably post a longer rant about this soon. (This answer, as is the norm for answers-used-as-polls, is CW.)

Comment: Existing copyright policy covers leakage of questions before a contest officially opens (if the problem text is unique, and if not, a solution is already published).  For contests in progress, an instant-close policy actually *helps* those who cheat, by maintaining their information advantage over the non-cheaters (who could at least check the answers to level the playing field, if alerted by the contest organizers and if MSE *kept the question open*).  Informing the contest organizers, and attaching an "Ongoing Contest" tag, are actions that do not restrict what can be discussed here.

Comment: Rant posted http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/it-would-be-harmful-to-design-all-mathematical-contests-to-be-proctorable/ . (Off site, to avoid being overly discussionny.)

Comment: I think closing is better than deleting when no answers have appeared. When answers have appeared, there is no good solution, but I think deleting is better than notification, as it hides the answer from cheaters who would google for it but not post a question. Most cheaters are extremely lazy. I can't imagine why keeping the question open could be better than closing it; more answers will only do more harm.

Comment: I'm confused about the convention on vote questions like this, I would have expected the convention was upvotes only.

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone can make a case that moderators should not have such power. We voted them into power. If they don't have these types of powers and must wait for consensus before doing anything, why even have moderators? Let's just do everything by consensus. If you don't like how a moderator's unilateral decisions go, then don't vote for them next time around. It is like any representative democracy.

Comment: @Noah My understanding is that "upvotes only" is the standard convention; that's why I created two complementary answers. As long as no one is double voting, I suppose it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: To point out explicitly what @NoahSnyder is saying implicitly, the two poll questions have received a number of up and down votes, so more people have voted than have appeared to do so. Hopefully, no one is abusing the system by voting twice.

Comment: In light of @Matt's comment, I think there is an ambiguity in both poll questions as to whether it means the moderators should wait for consensus on *general policy* (and implement the consensus mostly independently thereafter) or wait in *every specific instance* where a contest question is posted. If the questions are edited to clarify this, anyone who misunderstood can re-vote.  I interpreted Bill Dubuque's quote introducing the query as about general policy, but Matt's reading of the poll question is about individual instances.

Comment: @zyx I don't think there is ambiguity. The proposal is about contest questions. I was using hyperbole to make my point.

Comment: @Matt, under both interpretations the proposal is about contest questions, and the hyperbole was clear.  The poll can be read as about what moderators should do from now until a policy exists, or about what the ultimate policy should be.

Answer (score 46):

Those in favour of giving away IPs of suspected cheaters should imagine that such a policy would allow *me* to obtain the IP of *anybody* asking a question here: Simply copy-paste a recent question asked to a throw-away website that looks like an online contest and - as "organizer" of the "contest" - claim that the asker is cheating in this "contest" and demand his IP address.
Privacy is an important good that should not simply be thrown overboard.

Comment: Giving out IP addresses would be a really bad idea for many reasons, but it doesn't matter if anyone here wants to do that anyway. The SE privacy policy prohibits it and the moderators are bound to their agreement with SE, they're not allowed to give them out.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to clarify that there is also a reson behind that policy.

Comment: @mt_ That sounds far fetched. Setting up a site just to get a particular question deleted would take a maniac. Besides, the OP would naturally respond by creating a meta thread calling out a fake, and it would not take long for meta users to set the record straight.

Comment: @LVK: Yes, while it is also *possible* to do what mt_4 describes, maybe the *incentive* is a lot lower (for the average non-maniac). Then again, the average non-maniac won't be too interested in IP data either - but you know what kind of people are "out there".

Comment: @mt_: Right. I'd encourage everyone to leave a hint that there is an ongoing contest (until which date?) to allow others the *option* to refrain from unwillingly help cheaters.

Comment: @MadScientist Alas, the SE privacy policy might not be as strict as we think. For example the recent mass deletion of purported contest questions also included the same mod revealing to an external entity the fact that some users were posting from the same IPs. By cross-matching, this allowed the external entity to uniquely identify the user. One SE spokesperson said he thinks this is allowed by the SE privacy policy. I think we should convince them to reconsider. This could easily be abused by oppressive regimes etc with just a little social engineering, e.g. as Hagen suggests. Thoughts?

Comment: @BillDubuque, your comment is misleading. Our policy is stricter than many sites, and the implication that the information we provided allowed someone to ID a user they otherwise couldn't is unsupported. In both contests, the cheaters had been identified; the question was more around whether they were two bad actors or one. That said, in the interest of candor, while Qiaochu's actions don't violate the policy, I think I agree with your main point that mods should not share any info about IPs, real names, or emails with any third party, whether or not they happen to be an oppressive regime.

Comment: @Jaydles Not true. A moderator supplied information on relationships between account names and IP addresses that aided an external entity to personally identify an MSE user (or so they think, often these inferences are incorrect).  In my opinion this is a gross violation of privacy. Moreover, if SE is going to condone such rogue moderation decisions,  then it is the (vague) SE privacy policy itself that is misleading.

Answer (score 25):

Done. Some clarifications for everyone else:

- As Mad Scientist says in the comments, the SE privacy policy does not allow us to release anyone's IP addresses. This is not under our control.
- I strongly disagree with mixedmath's answer in the linked thread. When it is brought to my attention that a question is from an ongoing contest, my policy is to delete it until the contest is over. (Deleting a question is reversible, but openly posting a solution to an ongoing contest problem is not.)

Comment: I don't think it is our business to enforce rules of some external entity.

Comment: Moreover, moderators should not execute unilatateral deletions on such contentious matters, esp. since such deletions *cannot* be reversed by the community.

Comment: But if many users support such deletions, we would want a moderator to be able to do it in a timely fashion without having to wait to gather a couple of other users with very many points.  I think that often "unilateral" action is better, with the understanding that we can voice concerns and request policy change on meta.

Comment: @Bill: I strongly disagree. The whole point of any kind of action in a situation like this is to act before other people participating in the contest see the question. Waiting to make a decision until there is community consensus is practically equivalent to deciding not to delete the question.

Comment: @Qiaochu The charter of this site is not to teach ethics. Rather, it is to teach mathematics.

Comment: @Bill: I am not trying to teach anyone morals.

Comment: I agree with Qiaochu and Jonas: if a question is shown to be part of a contest/homework, I will not answer it until the contest/homework is over/due. I don't find temporary locking/deletion out of the question as it is temporary.

Comment: If a question has no answers, then temporary locking is sufficient. If a question has answers, then I see two possible *temporary* actions: 1. delete the question; 2. delete the answers and lock the question. These actions should be reversed as soon as the contest/homework is over/due. Temporarily locking the question has the benefit of letting others know that the question is part of a contest/homework.

Comment: @Robjohn It certainly is your prerogative to decide not to answer it. But it is not your prerogative to make that decision for others.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Indeed, the charter of this site is to teach mathematics. However, if we immediately answer questions that we know are on contests/homework, we do harm: harm to the others in the contest; harm to the student who does not learn from their homework; harm to the people who rely on someone, thinking they know things they don't. All decent questions posted on this site deserve an answer, but I see little harm in delaying that answer to an appropriate time.

Comment: @Robjohn The situation is highly analogous to homework questions The most reasonable policy is to let every user decide for themselves if/when/how they will answer based on whatever information is available about external matters. We should not cripple our site based on matters having nothing to do with us. It is the job of contest designers to take into account the large amount of knowledge easily accessible to participants. That is not our job.

Comment: Would this be acceptable to everyone/anyone? When a moderator becomes aware that a contest problem has been posted, the moderator edits into the question something to the effect of "This is a problem in the such-and-such contest. The contest closes on such-and-such a date. Please take this into consideration when thinking about posting a response."

Comment: I completely agree with Qiaochu and robjohn. And I do not agree that deleting/stalling contest questions would "cripple our site" as Bill says. In fact, I would like to think of MSE as beneficial to the mathematical community as well as individual students learning math - and to allow contest questions to be answered here harms the integrity of those contests. In addition, I am going to edit my answer that Qiaochu has referred to, indicating that this thread is the most recent thread about the idea of answering ongoing contest questions.

Comment: @mixedmath That's a very slippery slope. If you start allowing questions to be deleted because they are similar to questions elsewhere, then that opens the door to many analogous requests, e.g. temporarily delete older questions because they are current homework, take-home exams, etc. This is not our problem. Rather, it's a problem with folks using antiquated methods for tests, contests, etc. - methods that are a poor fit to the current information age. Any problems they encounter should be fixed at the source - not kludged here.

Comment: @Bill It may be a problem for MSE, specifically for its reputation (the one not measured in points). If the site comes to be perceived as a cheaters' paradise a la wedoyourhomework.com, MSE will have a hard time attracting new expertise that it sorely needs. Imagine all 12 Putnam problems posted and solved here on the morning of Dec 1 - what will be the reaction of math community?

Comment: @LVK We've never had that problem in the past, and I see no indications that it may occur in the future. If some folks want to give hints for these problems, or point to related literature, etc, then they should be allowed to do so.

Comment: Bill wrote: _temporarily delete older questions because they are current homework, take-home exams,_  I don't think something like this can be done. If a question is old, copy of the answers are in Google cache and many scraper sites. The way I see it, the recent discussion is about new questions.

Comment: There are clearly costs and benefits to enforcing any policy. I think temporary locking as advocated by Robjohn is a great compromise. I don't like slippery slope arguments in a world that is full of shades of grey.

Comment: @Martin Yes, that posts are cached by external entities such as Google, scraper sites, etc, is already on my list of reasons arguing against such a policy of temporary deletion.

Comment: Qiaochu, I hope you understand that this vigilante policy helps the cheaters in one way.  *They* know to follow the question closely for as long as it survives, and are auto-notified of replies. The *other* competitors do not know the question exists.  A saner method is for each of these long unsupervised contests to have its own blog where cases of online posting can be listed, with links.  This would reduce the incentive to cheat (if that is the incentive) by placing all competitors in the same state of information.

Comment: @zyx: Robjohn's suggestion of locking the question instead of deleting sounds like it will solve that problem beautifully.

Comment: @Henning, the locked and unlocked state are equivalent for "that problem" that I have just raised, so my comment cannot and should not be used as an argument for locking anything.  *Deletion* presents a problem, by maintaining the information asymmetry in favor of the "cheating" users, and I reiterate that the only way to eliminate the incentive for cheating is in the hands of the contest organizers, or any contest participants who care to neutralize the effect of cheating.  Setting up an RSS enabled blog (which is desirable for reasons independent of cheating) is the most obvious method.

Comment: @Henning The problem with temporarily locking or deleting the question is that this removes the capability to answer the question during its prime time of exposure - when it is on the front page of the *newest* questions list. If/when it is unlocked/undeleted it will receive far less exposure, and many readers will probably not revisit it.

Comment: @Michael: But if you don't allow slippery slope arguments then you won't allow ad hominem arguments either, and then you'll have to concede to stop using ad nauseum arguments... then at some point you will just have to ban all disagreements are arguments from this site!! :-)

Comment: @Bill: I don't know what about you, but seeing how I hope to have a future in the academy, I would very much like to avoid having a community I greatly participate in flagged as "cheaters heaven". I am fairly certain that I am not the only one.

Comment: @Asaf In two years we've had only one (new) user make such a remark. Yet our site prospers and serves a much better role pedagogically than does any site for contests. I see no need for concern about this matter.

Comment: @Bill: I'm sure I am not the only person who feels like that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I don't want to see MSE classified as a cheaters paradise, but after tossing about ideas with many people, it seems that MSE should not be relied on as the best means to hinder cheating. As mentioned earlier, deleting answers favors those who watch the answers closely or the question poster who has opted to have answers emailed to them. In this case, at least one answerer beat user31029 to the punch; thus, reacting to people warning us about contests is not a reliable strategy.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I think that the matter is best left to the contest coordinators. It seems the best that we can do when we find out about a contest is to alert the contest coordinators of our presence.  They can then watch out for contestants plagiarizing answers posted here.  Just as with take-home exams, there are difficulties with administering online contests due to the resources available on the web.

Comment: @robjohn: Oh, I don't think that we should immediately lock/delete/suspend. I do think that (1) agreeing on a policy and allowing moderators to act freely according to it is a **good** thing; (2) we should not separate ourselves from the rest of the online communities. We should strive for cooperation and mutual support, rather than dismissing that as "their problem".

Comment: @rob Yes, that's essentially my viewpoint. Attempting to do any more than notifying external entities opens up a big can of worms. We don't have enough information to make judgements about cheating. And how would we judge which (con)tests deserve recognition (e.g. a cranks can and do create online contests with rewards). Further, we'd need to be very careful not to mistakenly accuse someone of cheating - someone who may have stumbled upon the problem outside the contest, e.g. by word of mouth, and who may not be aware that it is a current contest problem. Worms galore.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I have contacted the contest coordinators and let them know of the two problems from their competition that have already been asked and answered. Both questions are tagged [tag:contest-math]. Unfortunately, there are more people answering questions than patrolling for possible contest questions, so they usually get answered before we find them.

Comment: The coordinators had already been notified of the cheating and in response have posted this: [Cheating on the OMO](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=810&t=500380).

Comment: @Bill Re: "We only had one user make such a remark." There is an observation bias here: people who make such remarks do not participate in the MSE. So the remarks are found [elsewhere](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1348/if-we-were-more-responsible/).

Comment: @LVK Ok, then that's $2$ folks in $2$ years who are so concerned about the possibility of cheating that they choose not to participate here. Among any large community there will always be some folks willing to throw out the baby with the bath water.

Comment: Let me remind you the Project Euler related discussions which are closely related to this. I'm sorry not to have the time right now to go through the meta and find the threads.

Comment: @Asaf I gess you are referring to [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/re-project-euler-questions).

Comment: @Michael: You "gess" correctly. In particular Will Jagy's answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is the complementary answer to my other poll question.

**VOTE THIS ANSWER UP TO OPPOSE the moderators rapidly deleting or closing questions from ongoing contests**, without waiting to seek consensus from the broader community.

(This answer is CW.)

Comment: I strongly oppose deleting or closing questions from ongoing contests. This is not about moderators vs the community, it's because I am opposed to the idea of giving contest organizers a monopoly on a mathematical question. I am disgusted that the Math.SE community seriously entertains this radical departure from scientific and academic traditions that do not recognize a monopoly on a scientific idea.

Comment: @Gilles Contest problems are not research problems. Contest problems are specially designed artificial questions meant to be solvable in the timeframe of a competition. Moreover, contests end and then the problems are available to the world.

Comment: Why should there be a difference between research problems and problems with a known solution? We had a similar issue on [cs.se] with [questions from a textbook where the author asked not to publish solutions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/394/answering-exercise-questions-from-textbooks-where-the-authors-explicitly-ask-oth): would you suppress such questions as long as the textbook is in print? If the question is not original (most aren't), what gives the contest author any right to it?

Comment: Umm, I don't know what contests you've worked on, but every contest I've been involved with took a great deal of pride in producing original problems. (I've written for the HMMT and submitted problems to the USAMO and Putnam.)

Comment: The issue of old chestnuts, like the fly going back and forth between two trains, has more grey areas. On the one hand, it would be silly to say that these questions should never answered online because someone might put them in a contest again. On the other hand, if I saw someone had actually pasted the specific phrasing of it from a math contest, I would post a comment urging others not to answer, because in that case answering would be helping a cheater.

Comment: "Specific phrasing" is copyrighted, which again suggests that the legal standard may be the one to use here rather than holding the site hostage to math competitions, homework, take-home exams and other such situations. There are hundreds of contests and thousands of the other categories at any moment.

Comment: Actually, I dispute that there are hundreds of contests which take place in an unproctored environment. I know of two: USAMTS and OMO . While proctoring is of course not perfect (especially in cases where local schools proctor nationwide contests, so there is a risk of proctors collaborating with cheaters) I imagine that simply being aware of these contests would cover most of the issues. Take home exams are a much harder problem.

Comment: @David: as well as USAMTS and OMO, there are numerous admissions problem sets for summer programs.

Comment: @D.Savitt Good point. That might be a harder case to deal with since I know that PROMYS, at least, reuses the same questions. That starts to run into Gilles' concern about whether a problem can be eternally off limits.

Comment: Canada/USA Mathcamp learned long ago that we shouldn't reuse questions, partly because we can't keep answers off the web indefinitely, partly because we think the problems are interesting and we do want to encourage discussion of them in the long run.  As a result we go to a lot of effort every year to write engaging problems that test what we want to test.  As a part of the mathematical community, we certainly appreciate the efforts of the broader community to keep things on the up-and-up in our admissions process.

Comment: @D.Savitt Good to know! Does Mathcamp put the questions for the current year online, so that we users here can spot them if they are asked?

Comment: Absolutely!  See http://www.mathcamp.org/prospectiveapplicants/quiz/index.php for last year's quiz (the committee to write next year's quiz just started working in the last couple of weeks).

Comment: There are dozens, and probably a hundred or two when taken internationally, of journals with problem columns, plus problem-of-the-week competitions and web sites (the IBM one was fairly prestigious).  Plus national IMO selection and training programs that include problems solved by correspondence.  Plus some qualifying exams in graduate school.  I could continue the list, but clearly the number is a lot higher than two or twenty.