# Is it unfair to post a live journal problem?

Tags: discussion, contests

I have received downvotes for posting live journal problem from Mathematical Reflections, mainly from the user [quasi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092988/is-1-ac23-b2-ge-frac548-for-a-polynomial?noredirect=1#comment4301821_2092988) for a number of problems.

I ask whether it is unfair to ask it? After the deadline, the journal itself publishes solutions, hence making the question less relevant. The journal is an open access journal. Also, I ask only for hints, and not readymade solutions. I am also of the opinion that it is much like someone posting their questions of homework for help. I have also viewed [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5007/should-we-allow-ongoing-journal-questions) link. Any views. Help appreciated.

Comment: Did you mention to user @quasi that you had posted this meta question?

Comment: "After the deadline, the journal itself publishes solutions, hence making the question less relevant." What is the relevance of your question then to begin with? Why can't you wait for the solution to be published in the journal?

Comment: At least wait until after the journal's deadline before posting here.

Comment: @Did : sorry to respond to a thread from a deleted post here but it shouldn't be too intrusive:  *@rschwieb How to ensure that "such tools" will "only (be) used for" that?* My point was that *lots* of tools can be misused, and that it is absurd to ask this. You may as well ask "how to ensure that a hammer will never be used to hit people over the head?" In our case, Will's proposed tool did not in itself harm anyone, so it is very much like the hammer. Sorry for the disruption here.

Answer (score 12):

> Is it unfair to post a live journal problem?

Yes.

Don't do that.

Comment: Do you still stand by your [suggestion from the previous thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5007/should-we-allow-ongoing-journal-questions/5008#5008) to create a separate tag for this kind of questions? (Since the time you posted that answer, this site has changed a lot. For example, homework tag has been removed.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Reading that, I remember my younger days. No, I don't stand by that anymore. I would now prefer if people simply did not post contest-style questions before the deadlines are up, within reason. And afterwards, I would tag them with [tag:contest-math], and include the journal/site and question number within the body of the question. I wonder what I'll think in another few years.